Ulalek + etb triggers
What if you have Ulalek, Fused Atrocity on the field and you cast an eldrazi spell with an etb like Brood Monitor do you get double etb effects on the cast and copy

Are you asking if you get 2 etb effects (one from the cast and one from the copy), or if you get 4 etb effects (one from the cast, one from the copy, and two more from Ulalek's doubling)?

No, you will have a total of 2 ETB triggers from Brood Monitor and the copy, not four.
The triggers need to be already on the stack when Ulalek's ability resolves for them to be copied, so when you cast an Eldrazi spell, only cast triggers will be on the stack to be able to be copied. Ulalek's ability will always be on stack above the creature that triggered it, so it will resolve before that creature enters the battlefield, before the ETB triggers and is able to be put on stack. Ulalek does not create a Panharmonicon effect for anything that happens after the effect resolves, any new triggers will work as normal.
If you are able to cast another eldrazi with flash, like Vile Redeemer after the copy of brood monitor entered (it will always be on stack above the card), you can copy the ETB of that Brood Monitor copy the eldrazi you cast with flash, and copy the original Brood Monitor still on the stack. This will give you 4 total Brood Monitor ETB triggers with 3 total Brood Monitors in play, however it's still better to do this while everything is still on the stack, giving you a total of 4 brood monitors, with each giving you one ETB for a total of 4 still.

Yes
Ulalek's text reads:

Devoid (This card has no color.)
Whenever you cast an Eldrazi spell, you may pay {C}{C}. If you do,
copy all spells you control, then copy all other activated and
triggered abilities you control. You may choose new targets for the
copies. (Mana abilities can’t be copied.)

If you pay for it, you will get a copy of the creature spell on the stack.  When the creature and the resulting copy hit the field, there is no reason to not expect them to both trigger.

I think you misread the question, OP is asking if the ETB triggers will be doubled panharmonicon style, giving each of the copies of Brood Monitor two triggers instead of the normal one.

@Andrew hmmm, seems a little unclear.  Let's ask them to clarify.

It's not unclear. ETB triggers are not cast triggers.

@Caleth What I meant was that it's unclear as to what the OP was asking.

@DavidRobie And I believe Caleth was disagreeing with you, as I did, it's pretty clear what OP was asking, if you double the etb triggers for the cast and the copy would mean two each, not if the copy gets etb triggers.
